# If one scenario fails continue with next Scenario in a cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

How can I continue running a feature on failure of 1 scenario to next?

Currently if first Scenario fails out of 10 (lets say) next 9 will not execute and it quits current session on driver/browser (WebDriver).

I am using Cucumber with Java, Junit, Serenity on Windows 7.

Comment: Is the failure due to an assertion error or some other exception? When it is assertion error then the next in order scenarios will be executed.

Comment: It is an assertion error. But didnt execute next scenario in feature file.

Comment: Do u have any code possibly in the after hook which closes the driver etc on failure?

Comment: No, I don't have anything as such. Its a baby project, after creating the serenity from maven command line, I only added 1 feature file. Rest everything is pre-configured.

Comment: Can you provide your feature file and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating all dependencies, plugins in `pom.xml` to their latest versions, fixed the issue.

Specially -

`maven-surefire-plugin`, `maven-failsafe-plugin`, `maven-compiler-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still facing the issue:

I was also getting same issue and resolved it by replacing hard assertions (`org.junit.Assert`) to soft assertions (`org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions`) in previous scenario that was failing.

For example:
**Before I was using:**

```
Assert.assertTrue("Error description",true);
```

**Resolved it by:**

```
softAssertion.assertThat(true).as("Error description").isTrue();
```